# If every element in a prime ideal $I$ is nilpotent, then $I=\sqrt{0}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I see a problem when I read [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518/why-does-a-minimal-prime-ideal-consist-of-zerodivisors?noredirect=1&lq=1).

As we know that $\sqrt{0}=\bigcap_{P\in \mathrm{Spec}{R}}P$, if every element in a prime ideal $I$ is nilpotent, then $I\subset \sqrt{0}$. Then
$I \subset \sqrt{0}= \bigcap_{P\in\mathrm{Spec}{R}}P \subset I$, so $I=\sqrt{0}$. I think something goes wrong but I do not know. Could you point out it to me?

Comment: Where do you get $ \bigcap_{P\in Spec{R}}P \subset I$ from?

Comment: Because $I$ is a prime ideal, $I\in Spec{R}$ then like what I write? Is it wrong?

Comment: If a prime ideal consists of nilpotent elements, then it coincides with $\sqrt{0}$, that's right. But the topic in the linked question is about every element of a minimal prime being a zero divisor, which is not the same as being nilpotent.

Comment: @egreg We can consider that it is also nilpotent

Comment: @LêThếLong Of course not.

Comment: If P is a minimal prime ideal then every elements in it is nilpotent. Is it right?

Comment: @LêThếLong Consider the ring $F\times F$, where $F$ is a field. The ideal $F\times\{0\}$ is prime and minimal. The ring has no nonzero nilpotent element.

Comment: I read the Rotman 's book "An introduction to homological algebra". Proposition 4.76 say that. Could you check it to me?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537115/question-concerning-commutative-algebra

Answer (score 1):

What goes wrong is that generally a minimal prime ideal does *not* consist of nilpotent elements.

Example. Consider a field $F$ and the ring $R=F\times F$. This ring only has four ideals, $\{0\}\times\{0\}$, $F\times\{0\}$, $\{0\}\times F$ and $R$. The two middle ones are minimal (and maximal) prime ideals. On the other hand, the ring has no nilpotent element.

What's true is that *if a prime ideal consists of nilpotent elements* then it equals $\sqrt{0}$. However, what's generally true is that a minimal prime ideal consists of zero divisors, which is a very different property than nilpotency.

---

Your doubts seem to come from a wrong statement in Rotman's book. Let's see what happens.

If $P$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$, then the localization $R_P$ has exactly one prime ideal and therefore any element in it is nilpotent. Therefore, if $x\in P$, then $x/1$ is nilpotent in $R_P$, so $x^n/1=0$ for some $n>0$, which means

> there is $s\in R\setminus P$ with $x^ns=0$.

Hence $x$ is a zero divisor. Indeed, if we choose $n$ minimal, we have $x^{n-1}s\ne 0$, because $x^{n-1}/1\ne0/1$.

Comment: I read the Rotman 's book "An introduction to homological algebra". Proposition 4.76 say that. Could you check it to me?

Comment: Is it the solution is wrong at "x is nilpotent if and only if x/1 is nilpotent". I think it is just true in the part "if".

Comment: @LêThếLong  I just looked at the statement in Rotman you quote in your comment, and it is wrong.  I am surprised that there is such a serious and basic error in this text, but there it is.  As you say, the if part is true, but in the other direction, all you get is that $x^n s = 0$ for some element $s \not\in \mathfrak p$.  This gives that $x$ is a zero divisor, but you can't do better than that, as the most basic examples show.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I am satisfied.

Comment: @LêThếLong Sorry, I don't have the book. Anyway, the example should be clear enough to remove your doubts. When you localize at a minimal prime, you indeed get that all elements in the (unique) prime ideal are nilpotent, but it's clearly false that if $x/1$ is nilpotent then $x$ is nilpotent.

Comment: There is quite a long errata to Rotman's book on homological algebra (unfortunately), but it is there.